# How to read Specific Map Key Value in case of an Array Object

Tags: java

I have the following Map structure

```
{empId=1234, empName=Mike, CDetails=[{"collegeName":"Peters Stanford","collegeLoc":"UK","collegeLoc":"UK"}]}
```

I need to read the value **collegeLoc** from the above Map

I tried this way  , its working , but  is there any better way

```
    myMap.entrySet().stream().filter(map -> map.getKey().equals("CDetails")).forEach(e -> {

            List<Object> objsList = (List<Object>) e.getValue();

            for(int i=0;i<objsList.size();i++)
            {
                HashMap<String,String> ltr = (HashMap<String, String>) objsList.get(i);

                System.out.println(ltr.get("collegeLoc"));
            }



        });
```

Comment: The value mapped to `CDetails` is a *list*, but you're casting it to a `HashMap`. You would have to cast it to a list first and then loop through that list's elements (and cast each to a map)

Answer (score 1):

`CDetails` is a *`List`*, not a `Map`.

Try this:

```
empMap.entrySet().stream()
  .map(map -> map.get("CDetails"))
  .filter(Objects::nonNull)
  .flatMap(List::stream)
  .map(element -> ((Map)element).get("collegeLoc"))
  .filter(Objects::nonNull)
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: @Lavanya I corrected a couple of errors, but you haven't provided enough detail for me to do more.